# how to terminate hover state on iphone

Tags: css, iphone, hover

I have a list of products with icons for contents. When hovering an icon a text explains the meaning of the image.

Because on touchscreens hover doesn't exist, I use :active, too.

My solution works perfect 
 - on desktop (hovering shows text, moving mouse away: text disappears)
 - and on normal phones (touch shows text, touching somewhere else: text disappears

but not on Iphones: touch shows text, but it stays even when touching somewhere else (except when touching another "hoverable" image)

HTML:

```
<span class="canhover">
    <img class="icon24" src="img/allergens/gluten.jpg">
    <span class="hovertxt">
        contains gluten
    </span>
</span>

<span class="canhover">
    <img class="icon24" src="img/allergens/milk.jpg">
    <span class="hovertxt">
        conains milk
    </span>
</span>
...
```

CSS:

```
.canhover {
    position: relative;
}
.canhover:hover .hovertxt, .canhover:active .hovertxt {
    display: block;
}
.hovertxt {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; bottom: 2em; left: 0;
}
```

How can I achieve that the text also disappears on I phones when toching somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `:focus` with `:hover` & `:active` like this :

```
.canhover:hover .hovertxt,
.canhover:focus .hovertxt,
.canhover:active .hovertxt{
    display: block;
}
```

and in safari browser use safari [prefix](https://bitsofco.de/css-vendor-prefixes/)